# ServiceMode/Android.mk: Specifies both LOCAL_SDK_VERSION (system_current) and LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS (true) but should specify only one

Tags: android, android-source, android-12, android.mk, android-firmware

I am an Android Firmware developer, working with a source of Android 12. I am facing an issue while I try to build a system application called ServiceMode. I am trying to build this application along with Android build and move it to system partition.

I get the below build error in Android.mk definition written by me:
"**Specifies both LOCAL_SDK_VERSION (system_current) and LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS (true) but should specify only one**"

In my makefile I have mentioned only **LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS := true**, since I am using hidden APIs and I haven't mentioned **LOCAL_SDK_VERSION**. But still I am getting a build error stating that both LOCAL_SDK_VERSION and LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS are mentioned in Android.mk

My Android.mk file looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(call all-java-files-under, java/com/foo/example/servicemode)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(call all-java-files-under, java/com/bar)

ifeq "$(LOCAL_REGION)" "JP"
    LOCAL_MANIFEST_FILE := java/com/foo/example/servicemodejp/AndroidManifest.xml
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(call all-java-files-under, java/com/foo/example/servicemodejp)
endif

ifeq "$(PROJECT_SERIES)_$(LOCAL_REGION)" "US"
    LOCAL_MANIFEST_FILE := java/com/foo/example/servicemodeus/AndroidManifest.xml
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(call all-java-files-under, java/com/foo/example/servicemodeus)
endif

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := ServiceMode
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_ODM_MODULE := true
LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := com.bar.twoworlds.mobile\
    com.foo.example.mobileinput.provider.util \

ifeq "$(LOCAL_REGION)" "JP"
    LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES += com.foo.example.jp
endif

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    com.foo.example.osdplanevisibilitymanager \
    com.foo.example.provider.modelvariation.util \
    com.foo.example.hardware.display-V1.0-java\
        android-support-annotations

ifeq "$(PROJECT_SERIES)_$(LOCAL_REGION)" "US"
    LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += com.foo.example.mobileapi
endif

LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled

LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS := true

LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
    
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    com.foo.example.osdplanevisibilitymanager:libs/com.foo.example.osdplanevisibilitymanager.jar

ifeq "$(PROJECT_SERIES)_$(LOCAL_REGION)" "US"
    LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += com.foo.example.mobileapi:libs/mobileapi-1.13.0.jar
endif

include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apps in vendor/odm/product partitions are not allowd to use private api.](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:build/make/core/local_systemsdk.mk;l=18?q=core%2Flocal_systemsdk.mk)

```
ifdef BOARD_SYSTEMSDK_VERSIONS
  # Apps and jars in vendor, product or odm partition are forced to build against System SDK.
  _cannot_use_platform_apis :=
  ifneq (,$(filter true,$(LOCAL_VENDOR_MODULE) $(LOCAL_ODM_MODULE) $(LOCAL_PROPRIETARY_MODULE)))
    # Note: no need to check LOCAL_MODULE_PATH* since LOCAL_[VENDOR|ODM|OEM]_MODULE is already
    # set correctly before this is included.
    _cannot_use_platform_apis := true
  else ifeq ($(LOCAL_PRODUCT_MODULE),true)
    ifeq ($(PRODUCT_ENFORCE_PRODUCT_PARTITION_INTERFACE),true)
      _cannot_use_platform_apis := true
    endif
  endif
  ifneq (,$(filter JAVA_LIBRARIES APPS,$(LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS)))
    ifndef LOCAL_SDK_VERSION
      ifeq ($(_cannot_use_platform_apis),true)
        ifeq (,$(LOCAL_IS_RUNTIME_RESOURCE_OVERLAY))
          # Runtime resource overlays are exempted from building against System SDK.
          # TODO(b/155027019): remove this, after no product/vendor apps rely on this behavior.
          LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := system_current
        endif
      endif
    endif
  endif
endif
```

The rule is enforced to make sure that the system img(Android Framework) can be upgraded while the other img are not upgraded.

You have set LOCAL_ODM_MODULE to true, which will caused that LOCAL_SDK_VERSION are set as system_current. Then the error message will be shown.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/787182/yong, thanks a lot for noticing the issue. Your suggestion helped me to solve the build error. I have removed LOCAL_ODM_MODULE from Android.mk and kept LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS alone.